# Keep track of a running time difference in a separate column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database which accepts log reports from multiple clients (computers).
Each row contains a clients name, some data, and a timestamp column with a time, when the log arrived in DB.

I want to calulate (in retrospective, for further analysis) the running time difference between the two latest times and store that in "time-diff" column.
This then translates to "duration" of that log record.

I already solved that for future records by trigger before insert, but I need to calculate this for all the records in history.

Please note, that the table with logs have cca **1M** records.

I can do the 'select' of this, using the code below.
What I am struggling with, is saving the difference to the correct row.
(`timestamp_diff(a, b) -> a - b` being my custom function, tested, returning difference in seconds).

So far I tested the select only on 2 computers, there are 100+ of them.

```
select computername,
       datetime,
       timestamp_diff(datetime, lag(datetime) over (partition by computername order by datetime))
from table_with_logs
where computername in ('AAAA', 'BBBB')
```

The table then should look something like this:

```
COMPUTERNAME    DATETIME                            TASK         DIFFERENCE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
AAAA            25.09.19 13:51:26,000000000 +02:00  IDLE         121
AAAA            25.09.19 13:53:27,000000000 +02:00  COMPUTING    121
AAAA            25.09.19 13:55:27,000000000 +02:00  IDLE         120
AAAA            25.09.19 13:57:28,000000000 +02:00  COMPUTING    121
AAAA            25.09.19 13:59:29,000000000 +02:00  OFFLINE      121
```

I'm basically looking for the right `UPDATE` statement.

In python pseudocode, it would look something like this:

```py
for row in table:
    previousRow.diff = row.time - previousRow.time
```

All this is so I can then easilly do:

```sql
SELECT computername, task, SUM(DIFFERENCE)
FROM table_with_logs
GROUP BY computername, task
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: So you basically want to take the first datetime and the last datetime and calculate the difference? This is per computer ? for the log entries?

Comment: I suggest you don't store values that can be calculated on demand when they are needed.

Comment: Why can't you just do `UPDATE table_with_logs SET time_diff = timestamp_diff(datetime, lag(datetime) over (partition by computername order by datetime))` or by doing an INNER JOIN against your current SELECT query?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I tried that, but I get an:
`SQL Error: ORA-30483: "window  functions are not allowed here" `

Comment: Even with an inner join?

Comment: @mustaccio I just updated the DB to calculate this with every new log, using trigger before insert. So to the future I'm fine. I just need to recalculate this few milion logs back. So I can then do something like `SUM(time_diff) group by computer, etc... `

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Can you please elaborate more on the version with the inner join? I'm not sure I understand correctly what you mean on how that can be put together.

Comment: `UPDATE table_with_logs t1 INNER JOIN (**your select**) t2 ON t1.computername = t2.computername AND t1.datetime = t2.datetime SET t1.time_diff = t2.diff` where `diff` is an alias for the result of timestamp_diff

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I see. That sounds possible. I will try that on a smaller set. How about efficiency? Wouldnt that be O(n2)?

Comment: Does it matter, is it a real life problem? You will run this once for all current records but after that you could add some where condition since you only want to update the newest rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Thinking outside the box

My friends, in the end I solved this quite easilly.
It turned out, that the fastest way would be, creating a new table as a modified select from the previous and then dropping the old one.

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE_UPDATED
AS
(select timestamp_diff(datetime, lag(datetime) over (partition by computername order 
 by datetime)) as diff, 
 MY_TABLE.*
 from MY_TABLE)
```

This takes only up to two minutes to run. I thank all for their effort.
Now it takes only some housekeeping to reapply the constraints (for which I will write some code) and wrapping this in a loop for all my log tables.

I hope this will help somebody in future.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need an `update`?  Why not just run a query like this?

```
select computername, task, sum(difference)
from (select l.*,
             timestamp_diff(datetime, lag(datetime) over (partition by computername order by datetime))
      from table_with_logs l
     ) l
where computername in ('AAAA', 'BBBB')
group by computername, task;
```

I don't see an advantage to modifying the data model.

Comment: I can select the information, but I need to have it stored back, so other processe can use this table easilly, using the sums and group by's and not need to do this select all over again.

Comment: @JakubČervinka . . . Other processes can use `lag()`.  You can even hide it in a view.  It is not clear to me that this data needs to be stored.